# Make a div fixed at particular height

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

In my web layout i am using a left side bar and a content div.Both of them want to scroll but at a certain point when left side bar content has finished the left side bar div div has to come as fixed and content alone want to scroll

Comment: You should try to make a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: js fiddle....?????????

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript or as in this example jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var divTop = $("#div-name").offset().top,
        stopPoint = 400;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= (divTop + stopPoint) && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('#div-name').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px',
            'height': '300px',
            'overflow-y': 'scroll'
        });
    }
});
</script>
<style>
    #div-name
    {   
        margin-top:45px;
        padding:15px;
        width:250px;
        height:1200px;
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
</style>
```

The first line calls the jQuery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The following script finds the div by it's ID and gets it's top most point.
The stop point is how far you want the div to scroll before stopping.

The if statement kicks in when the screen scrolls past the stop point and alters the css to set the position to fixed plus anything else you want it to do.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are saying but:

Give the div a height in the css. For example:

```
#div_name {
    height: 575px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, here's what you need!

http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/